# How to use HTTPS URL in SoapUI

Tags: soap, soapui, soap-client

I was using HTTPS URL in `wsdl` link. I want to configure HTTPS URL in `soapui`. I was trying but getting below error:

> org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: java.net.UnknownHostException:

I was using the URL below in `SoapUI`:

https://truepartswspx.com/ProcurementService/Proxy/InvoiceSvc?wsdl

Thanks.

Comment: Looks the wsdl url is not accessible, hence the error. Try accessing it using browser.

Comment: The url is not complete. It has client name which I removed. It works fine in my browser.I now get the below error in soapui.
java.lang.Exception: Failed to load url;

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the url has some issue, as its not loading on browser.

Comment: The url is not complete. It has client name which I removed. It works fine in my browser.I now get the below error in soapui.
java.lang.Exception: Failed to load url;